# Проблема с БД

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, mysql

У меня все таблицы в innoDB, но под ними строчка

```
     15 table(s)     Sum    4   MyISAM  utf8_general_ci 240.0 KiB
```

Как сделать что-бы место MyISAM было innoDB

Comment: Ручками в PHPMyadmin как вариант не годится? Операции - параметры таблицы - Тип таблиц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Converting Tables from Other Storage Engines to InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)